# Why does XHR Request To Azure Event Hub have improper message body?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, azure

I am sending an Ajax XHR message to event hubs using JavaScript like so...

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: eventHubConfig.ServiceBusUri + eventHubConfig.AdHubName + "/messages/?timeout=60",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", SASToken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }
    });
```

The Payload is a simple object which is stringified to JSON format something like...

```
    var payload = {
        platformId: 2,
        articleId: 3,
            ...
            ...
        Type: "ViewType"
    };
```

The message when read from the event hub looks like..
[image: Correct Message]

Occasionally I receive a message which looks like...
[image: Incorrect Message]

Please note that these are both the body of the message after getting the UTF8 string from the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData object in the C# backend like so...

```
    var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
```

Any ideas on how it would be possible for the Event Hub to receive the second message?